# Time Complexity of input a data

Tags: c++

There is any cost of taking 2d array as input ?

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
     cin >> a[i][j];
   }
}
```

Is it O(n^2) time complexity  or O(1)?

Comment: both loop run for n iterations, so it is n^2.

Comment: The time-complexity of the loop is one thing, the "complexity" of the actual input another. In terms of time-measurement the input itself will dwarf the time the code will execute,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time Complexity depends on how you define it. In competitive programming, there is a chance that you might be given a readymade 2D matrix and you have to find out a particular answer.
Now, what approach you take while finding out the answer defines your time complexity. But in this case, taking input is not taken into account while defining time complexity as you need a 2D matrix for your use.

In simple terms, if you are given n as a variable and you need to take input of n*n elements, the complexity is O(n^2).

Comment: Please provide feedback for the answer. Upvote and accept it if it helped you